# How to use YouTube analytics monetary

Tags: youtube-api

I am trying to access earnings and monetizedPlaybacks from the YouTube analytics API and all I am able to get is "401 Unauthorized"-Responses. I have logged in using OAuth2 and I used the scopes

- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/yt-analytics-monetary.readonly
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/yt-analytics.readonly
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly

Here is the Java-Snippet that I use in my application:

```java
analytics.reports()
        .query("channel==" + channelId, "2013-06-01", "2013-07-01", "earnings,views,monetizedPlaybacks")
        .setFilters("video==" + videoId)
        .setDimensions("month")
        .execute()
```

I also tried to use the [APIs Explorer](http://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/), but this behaves identical.

If I retrieve only the number of views (no earnings and not monetizedPlaybacks) everything works fine.

I found [this bugreport](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=4826) that claims that the API is broken, but it causes remarkably few reactions.

Any ideas appreciated.

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17946003/how-to-use-the-youtube-analytics-api-to-get-the-metric-earnings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature is currently not available in the API for youtube partner even though the information can be retrieved using the GUI. Instead a CMS-Account is needed.

There is a bugreport / feature request about the issue:

https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=4826