# How to use the Youtube Analytics API to get the metric "earnings"?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-analytics

I am a Youtube Partner and I have monetized videos on Youtube. Already receive a small monthly amount through some channels that have associated with my Google Adsense account.

Now, I would like to generate a report gathering the monetary values and views received from each channel.
I did the following question on Google Code, because I thought there was some problem in the API, but it happened that I was using the API incorrectly. See the link below.

http://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=4826#makechanges

Now, I still could not make it work because I do not know where to find the requested data in the response I got from the link above.

Where do I find this CMS_ID? I have more than one channel, so I need to have each accepted as a Youtube Content Manager to use the API and retrieve the gains?
Someone here on Stack Overflow already managed to use the Youtube Analytics API using the metric "earnings"?

My code is in Python based on the example from Google here:

```
https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/code_samples/python
```

I'm using the following scopes:

```
YOUTUBE_SCOPES = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly",  
                      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/yt-analytics.readonly", 
                      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtubepartner",
                      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/yt-analytics-monetary.readonly"]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of right now, it's only possible to retrieve monetary information in YouTube Analytics API reports when those reports are run via the context of a content owner, as described in [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/content_owner_reports).

It is possible to have a monetized channel that is opted in for Google AdSense ads without having that channel managed by a content owner, in which case you would not be able to get those metrics via the YouTube Analytics API.

Let's use [the issue you previously opened](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=4826) to track the request to open up this type of report to non-content owners as well, as that's a more appropriate place for feature requests than Stack Overflow.

Comment: Hi Jeff, Any ideias on how can I get this information without using the API?