# Youtube Analytics API returns Insufficient permission to access this report

Tags: youtube-api

Whenever I try to get an earnings related metric in the API, it returns "Insufficient permission to access this report". But when I remove it and replace with simple metrics like "views" or "likes", it works.

Here's the request:

https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#search/youtube%20analytics/youtubeAnalytics/v1/youtubeAnalytics.reports.query?ids=channel%253D%253DMINE&start-date=2013-01-01&end-date=2017-02-04&metrics=views%252CestimatedRevenue&_h=1&

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I try it my self and like you, I also got the 401 error when I use the metrics estimatedRevenue.

I found here in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17946003/how-to-use-the-youtube-analytics-api-to-get-the-metric-earnings) that it's only possible to retrieve monetary information in YouTube Analytics API reports when those reports are run via the context of a content owner, as described in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/content_owner_reports).

This linked [issue](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=4826) might also help you.

Comment: That's weird. My code was working weeks ago. I got all the data and saved it to the database. It only stopped working last January 30.

Comment: @ravenjohn Hello, did you find the solution to this problem ?

Comment: @Gransfall you should check the linked issue. YouTube decided to disable it and just stated in the API History that it is not possible to get earnings-related analytics using a channel's own access token.

Comment: @ravenjohn  i was not sure because my english is not so good,Thanks for your answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript

```
var OAUTH2_SCOPES = [
  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube',
  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl'
];
```

to retrieve comments from the YouTube API add
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl
this into OAUTH2_SCOPES array